# Prometheus: scraping a 'bare metal' target without a Prometheus client library

Tags: prometheus

I'd like to use Prometheus to collect data from a remote, microcontroller-based sensor.  The sensor does not run an OS, nor can it use the client libraries provided by Prometheus, but it can serve http connections.  Would this be appropriate html data to provide a 'gauge' to the server?

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><pre> gauge_val 200 </pre></body></html>`

If not, how is this best done?

Answer (score 1):

Metrics can be exposed to Prometheus using a simple text-based exposition format (that's what client libraries do for you). The format looks like this:

```
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3
```

The specification is available [here](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md).

You need to write a text file in this format and make it available via HTTP. Don't use HTML, it has to be simple text file.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've done this and see that the server reports a 'malformed HTTP status code'.  The exact error is net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP version "this_metric".  This is what led me to believe it needed to be HTML.  If I manually browse to http:<ip address>/metrics, the browser downloads the exact file as expected.  Do you have ideas on how to get past this error so that prometheus will accept the file as a scrape?

Comment: @Gwentech Nortmally browser shouldn't download metrics as a file. They should be visible right in browser and I suppose that the problem is wrong `content-type` header (you need something like `Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8`). What is the web server? Is it Nginx or Apache?

Comment: The web server is an embedded microcontroller, neither Apache nor Nginx; just a raw TCP connection on port 80.  Upon receiving a GET http message, the (embedded) web server is responding with raw data 'this_metric 200\x0D\x0A' for the Prometheus server.  A header may be needed, but I'm trying to pin down how the data is formatted on this low socket level.  Ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: @Gwentech seems like a worthy challenge. Is there any documentation for the embedded web server? Or what's the controller name, I'll try to find myself.

Comment: Well, here's a reference to the web server source ([Microchip ASF httpd reference](https://asf.microchip.com/docs/latest/sam3x/html/httpd_8c.html)).  It's really just the socket level handling of a http server and might not shed much light on this exactly.  I suppose if I were to network sniff how the example Prometheus client responds to itself on localhost, I'd see the raw data and could mimic the formatting.  Sounds tedious though.  Open to other ideas.

Comment: @Gwentech I've ran a minimal setup in docker and it seems that there's little to do to make it working (see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anemyte/4f4233c3c568da24dcfa11f04e124769)). Perhaps there's something with the content of reponse, try capturing a response from your controller and compare it with the one from the gist.

Comment: Yes, I was finding similar results while network sniffing, but this is very helpful.  The response format shown in the tcp dump is what must be needed.  I will try this. Thank you!